# Расположение элементов в layout, а именно в ListView - ImageView и TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, textview

Вот, собственно, результат:

[image]

Это у меня новости `RSS`. Я хочу, что бы картинка была сверху, а краткое описание под ним.

`image_text_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/feed_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="3dip" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/job_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000a2c"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="28dip" 
        android:paddingLeft="8dip"
        android:paddingRight="8dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`news.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000a2c"
        android:dividerHeight="0px" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вам надо почитать про фундаментальные вещи в Android
[link][1]

[1]: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/15-urok-6-vidy-layouts-kljuchevye-otlichija-i-svojstva.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У `LinearLayout` ориентацию сделать вертикальную `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 3):

Или используйте RelativeLayout